# C# Bonus Calculator

Tags: c#

Create a  Bonus Calculator program that has two overloaded methods----one that accepts the salary and bonus both expressed as doubles and one that accept the salary as a double and and the bonus as an int.

I wrote the program and I can get the bonus as an int to work but both of them as double will not work

```
namespace BonusCalculation
{
 class Bonus
 {
   static void Main(string[] args)
   { 
        double salary;
        int bonus;
        double bonusPercent;

        WriteLine("What is your salary?");
        salary = Convert.ToDouble(ReadLine());
        WriteLine("What is your bonus?");
        string bonusString = Console.ReadLine();
        if (int.TryParse(bonusString, out bonus))
        { CalcBonus(salary, bonus); }
        else if((double.TryParse(bonusString, out bonusPercent)))
        { CalcBonus(salary, bonusPercent); }

        WriteLine( "Your new salary is {0:c2}", CalcBonus(salary,bonus));
    }
  static double CalcBonus(double s,double b)
    {
        s = (s * b) + s;
        return s;
    }
 static double CalcBonus(double s, int b)
    {
        s = s + b;
        return s;
    }
  }
}
```

When I run the program with a double as the bonus it doesnt do the math. Thank for any and all help.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't do the math"?  What inputs are you providing and what outputs do you get?

Comment: Also, I would have the user specify if the input is a value or a percentage rather then trying to infer it when you parse.  `20` is both a valid `integer` and a valid `double`.

Comment: Your program is very confusing.  You have two calls to `CalcBonus` that do nothing with the return value, then you have another call to it that is in the WriteLine call.  I think you need to rethink your logic.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
    if (int.TryParse(bonusString, out bonus))
    { CalcBonus(salary, bonus); }
    else if((double.TryParse(bonusString, out bonusPercent)))
    { CalcBonus(salary, bonusPercent); }

    WriteLine( "Your new salary is {0:c2}", CalcBonus(salary,bonus));
```

if `bonusString` is not a valid integer, `bonus` is never set, and the last call to `CalcBonus` in the `WriteLine` uses `0` as the bonus value.

Rather then trying to infer the bonus type, have the user specify if they're entering in a percentage or a value, and only do the math once rather than doing it again the the `WriteLine` call.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // Constant field for the contribution rate
    private const decimal CONTRIB_RATE = 0.05m;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // The InputIsValid method converts the user input and stores
    // it in the arguments (passed by reference). If the conversion
    // is successful, the method returns true. Otherwise it returns
    // false.
    private bool InputIsValid(ref decimal pay, ref decimal bonus)
    {
        // Flag variable to indicate whether the input is good
        bool inputGood = false;

        // Try to convert both inputs to decimal.
        if (decimal.TryParse(grossPayTextBox.Text, out pay))
        {
            if (decimal.TryParse(bonusTextBox.Text, out bonus))
            {
                // Both inputs are good.
                inputGood = true;
            }
            else
            {
                // Display an error message for the bonus.
                MessageBox.Show("Bonus amount is invalid.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Display an error message for gross pay.
            MessageBox.Show("Gross pay is invalid.");
        }

        // Return the result.
        return inputGood;
    }

    private void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Variables for gross pay, bonus, and contributions
        decimal grossPay = 0m, bonus = 0m, contributions = 0m;

        if (InputIsValid(ref grossPay, ref bonus))
        {
            // Calculate the amount of contribution.
            contributions = (grossPay + bonus) * CONTRIB_RATE;

            // Display the contribution.
            contributionLabel.Text = contributions.ToString("c");
        }
    }

    private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Close the form.
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: How does this code solve the problem? Explain please.